# Converting several pdfs to tiffs with ghostscript in one call, and keep reference to originale file

Tags: pdf, command-line-arguments, ghostscript

I'm trying to convert several multipage pdfs to several single pages tiffs.
I want to do it with one single command and perserve reference from single tiff to original pdf.

Now I'm using

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dNoVerifyXref -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -r300 -dBATCH -sOutputFile=page-%d.tiff pdf1.pdf pdf2.pdf ... pdfn.pdf
```

with the resulting files

```
page-1.tiff, page-2.tiff ... page-m.tiff
```

where m is the totalt number pages combined in all inputted pdfs.

### What I want to achieve

Is it pssoible to update the command to instead get the resulting files:

```
[pdf name]_[pdf page].tiff
```

eg. pdf1_1.tiff pdf1_2.tiff pdf2_1.tiff, if pdf1 has two pages and pdf2 one page.

Or similar

Note. Don't want any script examples, just looking for Ghostscript command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ghostscript devices (eg TIFF output) are independent of the input interpreter, because they are required to work with a number of different input languages (PDF, PostScript, XPS, PCL). As such, they are not aware of the fact that there are multiple input files, they simply see a stream of output to format up and deliver.

So no, you can't do that in a single invocation of GS. You can do it in a script by calling GS once for each input file but that is all.

Comment: Ok, to bad. I noticed a significant increase in performance while calling GS with several input files.